# How to describe a type so that string saved as a variable can be used to index it?

Tags: typescript

The logic has the following object:

```
export const CONFIG = {
    buttonDestinations: {
        detailedStats: `detailedStats`,
        mealPlans: `mealPlans`,
        products: `products`
    },
    buttonTexts: {
        detailedStats: `detailed stats`,
        mealPlans: `meal plans`,
        products: `products`
    },
    buttonConfigTypes: {
        detailedStats: `detailedStats`,
        mealPlans: `mealPlans`,
        products: `products`
    },
    navigationVisibilityThreshold: 100
}
```

Which is later used as:

```
let configType


switch (true) {
    case elementsVisibility.detailedStats:
        configType = CONFIG.buttonConfigTypes.detailedStats
        break
    case elementsVisibility.selectedMealPlan:
        configType = CONFIG.buttonConfigTypes.mealPlans
        break
    case this.isSelectedProduct:
        configType = CONFIG.buttonConfigTypes.products
    ...
}

if (configType) {
    button.destination = CONFIG[configType].destination
    button.text = CONFIG[configType].text
}

...
```

While TS warns:

```
TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ buttonDestinations: { detailedStats: string; mealPlans: string; products: string; }; buttonTexts: { detailedStats: string; mealPlans: string; products: string; }; buttonConfigTypes: { detailedStats: string; mealPlans: string; products: string; }; navigationVisibilityThreshold: number; }'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ buttonDestinations: { detailedStats: string; mealPlans: string; products: string; }; buttonTexts: { detailedStats: string; mealPlans: string; products: string; }; buttonConfigTypes: { detailedStats: string; mealPlans: string; products: string; }; navigationVisibilityThreshold: number; }'.
```

Can you please suggest what way can be chosen to allow keys of the same object to index it?

Comment: If you want better help, it may be a good idea to create an example case in https://www.typescriptlang.org/play , that way others can help you directly instead of guessing at the code.

Answer (score 0):

You solve this by declaring `configType` to be of type of keys of the CONFIG type, like this:

```
let configType: keyof typeof CONFIG;
```

You have another problem here, namely that you are assigning a value to the `configType`, whereas it's later used as if it were a key to `CONFIG`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want a [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions), meaning you declare to typescript that the CONFIG never changes and is not just a collection of strings.

```
export const CONFIG = {
...
} as const;
```